# prevent heroku from running "npm run build" on deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku

i have a MERN stack application that i wish to deploy to heroku, in my package.json file i have the "build" command in scripts, whenever i try to deploy heroku runs the build command automatically and fails, which fails everything else..i already use build on my local machine before deploying so i don't want the script to be run again.. i checked around and found this article in herokus dev logs

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573

it says if i wish to stop that from happening i need to "specify a heroku-postbuild script in  package.json file."

what is this postbuild script? how can i do that? can someone give me an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Heroku but this [link](https://dev.to/hjfitz/comment/21bk) provides an explanation on why you might need to build again on a deploy to Heroku and also gives a sample build script.

If you're sure you don't have to do any build on Heroku and just uploading (deploying) your files is enough, then your `heroku-postbuild` could just display (log) a message. The [example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) on Heroku's website for `heroku-postbuild`  simply displays (logs) a message.